# Automatic move in a map

Tags: php, algorithm, oop

I have a map with a size (10,10). I represent it with an object called `Map`. I have a `Monster` on it, on the position (5,5). This monster has to change position automatically at each `$turn` and depend of `$nbMove`. `$nbMove` is an attribute of the class `Monster`You choose it in the constructor of `Monster`.

`$nbMove` is the number of move before he makes a half-turn

Here is an example of what I want, when the game begins :

The game is in a loop `for($turn = 0; $turn<10; $turn++)`

So if `$nbMove` is 2. The monster goes to the case (5,6), the next `$turn`, he goes to (5,7), the next `$turn` he goes back to (5,6) and, the next `$turn` (5,5). the next `$turn` (5,6), the next `$turn` (5,7), the next `$turn` (5,6) etc ...

So if `$nbMove` is 3. The monster goes to the case (5,6), the next `$turn`, he goes to (5,7), the next `$turn` he goes to (5,8) and, the next `$turn` (5,7), the next `$turn` (5,6), the next `$turn` (5,5) etc ...

He should only go verticaly.

It's like a chess move but it's done by a computer and it always does the same thing.
Here is my code :

```
<?php 

class Monster { 
  public $horizontal;
  public $vertical;
  public $nbMove;

  function __construct($horizontal, $vertical, $nbMove) {
    $this->horizontal = $horizontal;
    $this->vertical = $vertical;
    $this->nbMove = $nbMove;
  } 
}

?>
<?php 

class Map { 
  public $width;
  public $height;

  function __construct($width, $height) {
    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $height;
  } 
}

?>
<?php

function moveMonster($turn, $monster, $map) {
  // The move 
  if(// I need a condition there but what condition ??) {
    $orc->vertical = $orc->vertical + 1;
  } else {
    $orc->vertical = $orc->vertical - 1;
  }
}

$map = new Map(10,10);
$firstMonster = new Monster(5,5,2);

for($turn = 0; $turn<10; $turn++){
  moveMonster($turn, $firstMonster, $map);
}

?>
```

I search how to make move my monster but I don't find any solution to do it. That's why I ask you a solution of my problem. I know how to make it move but it should depend of the number of `$turn` and `$firstMonster->nbMove` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Monster` needs to be able to keep track not only of its current position, but also how far it can go in either direction and which direction it's currently moving. If you don't have a way to maintain that state, then as soon as you move it the first time, you've lost the original Y position and have no way of knowing whether or not you're within `$nbMove` moves of it or whether you're moving toward or away from it.

If we add a few more properties to `Monster` to define those, and set them in the constructor, then it's easy for it to move within its defined boundary and change direction when it reaches the edge of the boundary.

```
class Monster {
    public $horizontal;
    public $vertical;
    public $nbMove;

    private $minY;
    private $maxY;
    private $direction;

    function __construct($horizontal, $vertical, $nbMove) {
        $this->horizontal = $horizontal;
        $this->vertical = $vertical;
        $this->nbMove = $nbMove;

        $this->minY = $vertical;
        $this->maxY = $vertical + $nbMove;
        $this->direction = 1;
    }

    function move() {
        // if at the top of the movement range, set the direction to down
        if ($this->vertical == $this->maxY) {
            $this->direction = -1;
        }
        // if at the bottom of the movement range, set the direction to up
        if ($this->vertical == $this->minY) {
            $this->direction = 1;
        }
        // then move
        $this->vertical += $this->direction;
    }
}
```

I showed `move()` here as a method of `Monster` because I thought it seemed more appropriate since moving would be something that `Monster` does. If you do it this way you would call `$firstMonster->move()` in the loop instead of the global `moveMonster()` function.

If you need to use `moveMonster()` then you could set those other properties as public and use the same logic in that function.